# I want to gather the host keys but ssh-keyscan command is not found on my linux. Anyway to achieve the same with some other commands

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, ssh-keygen

I want to gather the host keys but ssh-keyscan command is not found on my linux. Anyway to achieve the same with some other commands without adding this command explicitly.

I am running with Wind River Linux 8.0.

Comment: windriver Linux, or Wind River Linux?

Comment: @EightBitTony Wind River Linux

Comment: You might be able to do something like `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -N $hostname` for each host, and then pull all the keys out of `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

You may check before which keys are available via `ssh <host> -Q key-plain`. At least you can gather the host key in a visualized way via `ssh <host> -o VisualHostKey=yes`. I am not sure [if this is reversible](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83985/).